# Is there any numerical solution method for this kind of partial derivate equation?

Tags: numerical-methods, partial-derivative

I am trying to solve a partial derivate equation, after doing some algebra end up with the following form for the equation:

$$\dfrac{ \partial y}{\partial t}=a_2(x,t)\dfrac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}+a_1(x,t)\dfrac {\partial y}{\partial x}.$$

In the latter $t\in[0,T]$ and $x\in[0,X]$

Is there any numerical solution method for this kind of partial derivate equation?

**Note:** it has initial conditions.

Comment: are $a_1$ and $a_2$ known or unknown? if they are known then @user7530 is right it can be solved to the resolution you need with some finite difference scheme if you can calculate $a_1,a_2$ at each point of discretization, but if they are not known but we know some other properties for them to hold  it will be quite non-linear.

Comment: yes, $a_1$ and $a_2$ are known

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure... where are you getting stuck? This looks like a standard initial-value PDE that can be solved using methods even as simple as finite differences. Draw a grid on the $xt$ plane, using the notation $p_{i,j}$ for the value of a variable $p$ at $x=ih_x$ and $t=jh_t$,

$$\frac{y_{i,j+1}-y_{i,j}}{h_t} = a_2(ih_x, jh_t)\frac{y_{i+1,j}-2y_{i,j}+y_{i-1,j}}{4h_x^2} + a_1(ih_x, jh_t) \frac{y_{i+1,j}-y_{i-1,j}}{2h_x}.$$

Comment: Sure. Those are easy to incorporate into the above formulation. Where do you get stuck?

Comment: For now, the initial conditions that I have are $y(x,0)=y_0$ and $y(X,t)=y_1$, so the problem is that I can't evaluate $i-1$ nor $j+1$, just $i+1$ and $j-1$ starting from $i_{max}$ and $j=0$.

Comment: @GuadalupeAnimation There is something wrong with the problem formulation... you need boundary conditions at $x=0$, it is not enough to just know $y(X,t)$.